# Does intermediate value property imply that "inverse image of an interval is interval"?

Tags: real-analysis

Does intermediate value property imply that "inverse image of an interval is interval"?

I mean that: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function which has the intermediate value property. Can I say that $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is an interval too?

Comment: No. Look at $f(x)=x^2$, $ (a,b)=(1,2)$.

Comment: It says that the *image* of an interval is an interval.

Comment: What does it mean to take the inverse of an interval?

Comment: @SenZen: if $f:A\to B$ is a function and $C\subseteq B$ then $f^{-1}(C)$ is defined as $f^{-1}(C)=\{x\mid x\in A, f(x) \in C\}$ and called as *inverse image of $C$ under $f$*. The notation in question should be $f^{-1}((a,b))$

Comment: @I see, so a counterexample would be $f(x) = x^3 - x, C = (-1/2, 1/2)$ ?